# Progess on conjectures of Palis

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, differential-equations

I came across a "A Global Perspective for Non-Conservative Dynamics" by Palis. He has some conjectures

"Global Conjecture:

- There is a dense set $D$ of dynamics such that any element of $D$ has finitely many attractors whose union of basins of attraction has total probability;
- The attractors of the elements in $D$ support a physical (SRB) measure"

I was wondering if there was some progress made in recent times. I am especially interested in continuous-time DS. I.e. could the conjecture be proven e.g. for continuous smooth DS on compact manifolds?

Comment: You can take a look at the Carlos Matheus' survey http://carlos.matheus.perso.math.cnrs.fr/ems-palis.pdf
But the conjectures remain open. Most progresses have been made in the C1 topology. For the first conjecture, I believe the best answer so far was given by Crovisier-Pujals https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-014-0553-9